# How to enable code outlining in Visual studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

As like the native code outlining in the VS code editor, how to enable it in VS for mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio -> Preferences -> Text editor -> General -> Code folding.

Check the "Enable Code folding", "Fold #region by default" and "Fold Comments by default"

[image]